# Implementing Server-Side NPCs (Non-player characters)

Tags: java, sockets, udp, multiplayer, udpclient

I'm having a bit of an issue with a 2D multiplayer game I'm making in Java. It's my first game and I've got this far with the aid of many tutorials, so perhaps something simple is escaping me.

When a client logs in, it sends a login packet to the server, which checks the username stored in the packet against players already connected. If the name doesn't already exist, the player is added to a list of entities. (I know I need better validation to prevent 2 identical usernames, but I'm focusing on getting everything working first). The code that accomplishes this is below:

```
public void addConnection(PlayerMP player, Packet00Login packet) {

        boolean alreadyConnected = false;
        int connectionAttempts = 0;

        for (PlayerMP p : connectedPlayers) {
            if (p.port == -1) {
                p.port = player.port;
            }

            if (player.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getUsername())) {

                if (p.ipAddress == null) {
                    p.ipAddress = player.ipAddress;
                }

                if (p.port == -1) {
                    p.port = player.port;
                }
                alreadyConnected = true;        //if client is already connected, return true + do nothing

            } else {
                sendPacket(packet.getData(), p.ipAddress, p.port);  //send login packet with new player address and port if not already connected
                Packet00Login newPacket = new Packet00Login(p.getUsername(), p.x, p.y, p.getShortColour());     //+ colour?
                sendPacket(newPacket.getData(), player.ipAddress, player.port);     //sending new packet to update character position
            }

        }
        if (!alreadyConnected) {
            connectedPlayers.add(player);       //add new player data to connectedPlayers list if matching values aren't already present.
        }
    }

public void sendPacket(byte[] data, InetAddress ip, int prt) {                  //method to send data to a single client as byte array within datagram packet object.
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, prt);
        try {
            socket.send(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The entities being added are instances of the PlayerMP class, which includes the IP address and port of any connecting client (which is where the difficulty arises with NPCs). Once added to the list of entities, all connected clients are constantly updated when any client moves their player character, (which causes a move packet to be sent to the server), using the below code:

```
public void sendDataToAllClients(byte[] data) {                 //method to send packets to all connected players by looping through list and sending datagram packet to each stored address/port
        for (PlayerMP p : connectedPlayers) {
            sendPacket(data, p.ipAddress, p.port);
        }
    }
```

I can omit the NPCs from this method by comparing usernames again, so as to ensure that the server isn't sending data to a client that doesn't exist (it has no ip/port), but I cannot seem to register the NPC entity using sendPacket(newPacket.getData(), player.ipAddress, player.port); in the first piece of code as I get null address/port out of range exceptions when I try. So the issue seems to be that the server does not know how to register an entity without an address.

I think it's essential for the NPC to send a global login packet, or it will only be displayed on the local client, but I can't see a way around this issue. I tried to created a new class extending my Mob class (which is a super of PlayerMP), but then ran into issues with casting, even though both the newly created NPC class and PlayerMP are extensions of Mob, which is an extension of Entity, so there *shouldn't* have been issues with casting.

I have really hit a brick wall here and any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you would like to take a look at any other code and I would be happy to oblige.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say your main problem is, that your "base" class seems to be the player. But is an NPC really a more specialized player? Aren't they both entities? Probably they should both implement the methods for data updates, with the NPC simply acting on the data update and the player simply sending the data to the client...

Comment: Why not have you NPCs implemented inside the game and not have to send packets to them at all?

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for the reply. They are both entities (extended from Entity/Mob), which is why I don't understand why the casting isn't working. I can add the NPC entity from the client side, but this causes the location of the NPC to reset everytime a new client logs in (as the x and y co-ordinates are contained within the constructor). As I said, I did try a separate class for NPC but found that it then wouldn't render with my existing code as it didn't want to cast to PlayerMP, which is what the list on the server is.

Comment: Peter, I can do client-side NPCs, which would be fine for simple dialogue, but I want to implement some sort of combat system which requires NPCs to move and be in the same position for every client.